# Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal break statement within ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here i'm trying to break out of a loop within an nested statement as per various questions i've seen in stackoverflow none seems to work right now code is below.

```
for (var i = 0; (i < 10); i++) {
                var URL = "http://www.goibibo.com/hotels/search-data/?app_id=1c1cc02b&app_key=54829b227c915bd0267dec660271fa87&vcid=4675090819370906231&ci=20170720&co=20170721&r=1-1_0&pid=" + i

                $.ajax({
                    url: URL,                        
                    type: "GET",
                    success: function (data) {

                     shareInfoLen = Object.keys(data["4675090819370906231"]).length;
                        if (shareInfoLen > 0) {
                            alert('On Process');
                        }
                        else if (shareInfoLen === 0){
                            alert('Closed');                                
                            break;
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (reponse) { }
                });
            }
```

I have used **return false** over **break** i used condition **(i < 10 && j == true)** and return **j = false** on else if condition instead of **break**, as i will be using infinite loop like **for(var i = 0; ; i++)** i need to break out of the loop if the array is 0.

Comment: You have make use of promises or async/await in your case, as u r in a callback

Comment: can give a link of it for tutorial will be appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: Maybe you could explain a bit more detaild what you try to accomplish. Your code looks really messy and there sure is an appropriate solution for the problem. But the way you try to do it looks not really thought through.

Comment: You might be able to break out of a loop if you give the loop a name.

Comment: i have given the name like example: for{} and returning the value from else if but it didn't work also evolutionxbox

Comment: for { if (i > 0) {} else if(i == 0) { break;}} throws illegal error of break @Schlangguru

Comment: @rinki yeah. I tested it too. You can't break out from a loop inside a nested function.

Comment: Your `for` loop completes in a split nanosecond. The function you pass to `success` will only run sometime later, often seconds later. You can't `break` from your success callback function, because there is no loop to break by the time the function runs. You need to look a bit into asynchronous JavaScript, it's not a difficult topic, but you need a solid understanding of how the thing works.

Comment: Thank you @JohnWeisz sir i will look into it.

Answer (score -1):

Working code here.

```js
var result = true;

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                var URL = "https://www.goibibo.com/hotels/search-data/?app_id=1c1cc02b&app_key=54829b227c915bd0267dec660271fa87&vcid=4675090819370906231&ci=20170720&co=20170721&r=1-1_0&pid=" + i
               $.ajax({
                    url: URL,                        
                    type: "GET",
                    success: function (data) {
          if(result){
                    shareInfoLen = Object.keys(data["4675090819370906231"]).length;
                        if (shareInfoLen > 0) {
                            alert('On Process');
                        }
                        else if (shareInfoLen === 0){
                            alert('Closed');         
                            result = false;
                        }
                    }
                    },
                    error: function (reponse) { }
                });
              }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Important note: this will NOT reduce the number of requests, this will just not execute the success callback when the requests complete.